# How to select min and max from table by column score?

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to select min and max from table by column score ?
Is this possible with session query ?

```
class Player(Base):
    username = Column(String)
    score = Column(Integer)
    # more not impoortant columns
```

Comment: Could you please clarify do you need just minimum and maximum values of the score or Player record that has min score and Player record that has max score?

Answer (score 38):

For the case when you need to find minimum and maximum values for the score field. You can do this with a one query using min and max functions:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
qry = session.query(func.max(Player.score).label("max_score"), 
                func.min(Player.score).label("min_score"),
                )
res = qry.one()
max = res.max_score
min = res.min_score
```

Answer (score 17):

```
from sqlalchemy import func
max = session.query(func.max(Table.column)).scalar()
min = session.query(func.min(Table.column)).scalar()
```