# How can SQLAlchemy get the maximum value of a field?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy class/model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    my_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    my_field = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

How do I find the maximum value of `my_id` in the table?

I have seen [this soluttion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217860/how-to-select-min-and-max-from-table-by-column-score), however, that seems like such an ugly way to do it (and I don't even know how to apply it in my case!). When I want to query this table, I do something like this:

```
MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.my_field == "blah").one()
```

Can't I do something very similar to this to find the max value of `my_id`? 
Ideally, I would just replace the stuff inside `filter(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could add an [`order_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by) clause

```
MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.my_field == "blah") \
             .order_by(MyModel.my_id.desc()) \ 
             .first()
```

Comment: Works. Is it as efficient as a Max operation?

Comment: I would guess it is not (however difference should be minor), but I am not sure. You can try to profile it or check the db logs what query was emited in each case.

Comment: Mine results was: 0.27269 s (after querying all) and 3.09944**e-06** s (after using _func.max_)

Comment: Much less efficient than using `func.max`, don't use this.